# How to configure an Express app in Kubernetes to use an egress droplet for MongoDB Atlas connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up an Express.js application running in a Kubernetes pod to connect to a MongoDB Atlas database. I've set up an egress droplet to control and log the outbound traffic from the cluster. The IP of the egress droplet has been whitelisted in MongoDB Atlas, but the application still can't connect to the database. I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly configure the Express app, or the Kubernetes cluster, to route traffic through the egress droplet.

**Environment Details:**

**Express App:** Running in a Kubernetes pod.
**Egress Droplet:** Set up to control outbound traffic from the Kubernetes cluster.
**Database:** MongoDB Atlas, with the egress droplet's IP whitelisted.

**Current Configuration:**

1. **Network Policy:** I have a network policy in place that's intended to allow egress traffic from the pod to the egress droplet.

Here is my `allow-egress-via-gateway.yaml` that is applied:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-via-gateway
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchExpressions:
      - {
        key: app, 
        operator: In, 
        values: [
          express-app
        ]
      }
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 153.000.000.000/32  # The egress gateway IP
  # Additional rules for DNS traffic
  - ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
```

Here is my `express-deployment.yaml`, which creates the express-app pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: express-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: express-app
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: "$(date +%s)"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: express-app
        image: mydockerhub/myexpress-backend:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: express-env-secret
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-docker-credentials
```

2. **IP Masquerading:** On the egress droplet, I've set up IP masquerading rules in iptables to modify the source IP of the outgoing packets.
3. **Database Connection:** The Express app is configured to connect to MongoDB Atlas using a connection string provided by Atlas.

**Issues Encountered:**

Despite the above setup, the Express app fails to connect to MongoDB Atlas. The logs suggest it's a connection issue, likely related to the IP not being whitelisted, even though I've confirmed the egress droplet's IP is on the whitelist.

**Specific Questions:**

1. How should I configure the Express app or the Kubernetes pod to ensure it routes traffic through the egress droplet?
2. Are there any common pitfalls or additional steps I need to consider when setting up an egress controller for a Kubernetes cluster?
3. Is there any additional configuration required on the egress droplet to ensure it properly routes and logs the traffic from the Kubernetes pods?

Any insights, suggestions, or further diagnostic steps would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully resolved the issue by first deleting the existing droplet on DigitalOcean. After waiting for about an hour, I created a new droplet within the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) as my Kubernetes cluster, using a YAML configuration file. This approach was based on a tutorial titled "[Setting up a DOKS Egress Gateway using Crossplane and Static Routes Operator](https://github.com/digitalocean/container-blueprints/tree/main/DOKS-Egress-Gateway)," recommended by Digital Ocean support.

Here's the key part of the `egress-droplet.yaml` file I used:

```
---
apiVersion: compute.do.crossplane.io/v1alpha1
kind: Droplet
metadata:
  name: egress-gw-sfo3
spec:
  forProvider:
    region: sfo3
    size: s-1vcpu-1gb
    image: ubuntu-20-04-x64
    vpcUuid: <vpcUuid>
    sshKeys:
      - <ssh keys>
    userData: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # Install dependencies
      echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true | debconf-set-selections
      echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true | debconf-set-selections
      apt-get update
      apt-get -y install iptables iptables-persistent curl

      # Enable IP forwarding
      echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
      sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

      # Configure iptables for NAT
      PRIVATE_NETWORK_INTERFACE_IP="$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/interfaces/private/0/ipv4/address)"
      PRIVATE_NETWORK_CIDR="$(ip route show src $PRIVATE_NETWORK_INTERFACE_IP | awk '{print $1}')"
      PUBLIC_INTERFACE_NAME="$(ip route show default | awk '{print $5}')"
      iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "$PRIVATE_NETWORK_CIDR" -o "$PUBLIC_INTERFACE_NAME" -j MASQUERADE
      iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
  providerConfigRef:
    name: do-provider-config
```

This YAML file configures a new droplet in the sfo3 region with specific settings including an Ubuntu 20.04 image, and runs a custom user data script for initial setup.

A big part of the solution was just getting the droplet created so that it sync'd with the Kubernetes cluster.  Previously, I was running back to the Digital Ocean control panel and creating droplets there but that was all done in vain.  The solution was to follow their tutorial and create the Egress droplet by a yaml file and not the normal method of going through your D.O. Dashboard to do so.

After executing this configuration, the new droplet was successfully created and assigned a public IP. I then used this public IP to whitelist the droplet at MongoDB Atlas. This solution worked effectively, and I was able to establish a connection to MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Well done, good catch and upvoted. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77778006/6309) provided general guidance and best practices for setting up and troubleshooting network configurations in Kubernetes, IP masquerading, and Express application settings. But your answer is more specific to your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your [network policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) (`allow-egress-via-gateway.yaml`) correctly allows traffic to the egress droplet. The policy you provided looks correct, but double-check the egress droplet IP (the [cidr part](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource): `cidr: <Egress-Droplet-IP>/32`).

Make sure the deployment (`kubectl apply -f express-deployment.yaml`) is successful and the pod is running.

On the egress droplet, you might use a command like the following to set up [IP masquerading](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/ip-masq-agent/):

```bash
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Confirm that IP masquerading is correctly set up on the egress droplet. That step is very important for ensuring that responses from MongoDB Atlas are routed back to the correct pod.
So check if the IP masquerade rule is present in the `iptables` configuration: `sudo iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING`, look for a line similar to: `MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere  anywhere`

Verify that the egress droplet correctly routes traffic to MongoDB Atlas and logs this traffic. Make sure no firewall or security rules on the egress droplet are blocking traffic to MongoDB Atlas.

In your Express app, use environment variables to store the MongoDB connection string securely:

```js
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGO_URI;
```

Make sure the Express app uses the correct MongoDB Atlas connection string. That connection string should be stored securely, for example, in a Kubernetes Secret.

Verify that the necessary environment variables are correctly passed into the Express app via Kubernetes secrets or config maps.

```yaml
envFrom:
- secretRef:
    name: express-env-secret
```

Make sure to include error handling in your Express app for MongoDB connection, like:

```js
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(err => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));
```

You can also implement retry logic in your Express app, in case of transient network issues:

```js
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Retrying MongoDB connection...');
    setTimeout(() => mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }), 5000);
});
```

After all that, test the connection from within your pod (from the Express app to MongoDB Atlas)

```bash
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/bash
curl http://<mongodb-atlas-url>
```

And check the pod's logs: `kubectl logs <pod-name>`

Inside the pod, use network tools for diagnosing:

```bash
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/bash
ping <mongodb-atlas-url>
traceroute <mongodb-atlas-url>
```

(more cently, [`tracepath` or `mtr`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608799/7490))

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/atlas-operator/ak8so-quick-start-helm/#retrieve-the-secret-that-created-to-connect-to-the-database-deployment), you should be able to connect your express app with the database by retrieving secrets of the MongoDB Atlas and creating [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), see sample below:

```
kubectl get secret -n my-namespace my-project-cluster-name-dbadmin  -ojson | jq -r '.data | with_entries(.value |= @base64d)';
```

```
containers:
 - name: test-app
   env:
     - name: "CONNECTION_STRING"
       valueFrom:
         secretKeyRef:
           name: my-project-cluster-name-dbadmin
           key: connectionStringStandardSrv
```